# Check if CSV headers match, if they match continue parsing otherwise stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, papaparse

I am currently trying to add some validation of some description in regards to how I want a particular .CSV format to be before it continues parsing using PapaParse.

So my idea was to check the headers first and if they equate to the following:

`Extension, company, name`

Then continue parsing otherwise I can throw back an error message stating the format was wrong.

All the parsing is done using PapaParse.

Ave had no joy with it but below is the current code:

```
var result = [];

$("#CSV-Upload").click(function () {
        $("input[type=file]").parse({
            config : {
                header : true,
                skipEmptyLines : true,
                complete : function (results, file) {
                    console.log("This file done:", file, results);
                    var string = JSON.stringify(results['data']);
                    result.push(string);
                    console.log("CSV Array: " + string);
                }
            },
            complete : function () {
                console.log("All files done!");
            }
        });
        $("#csv-file").val('');
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to check if the certain key is present in the header. To do so using papa parse, I suggest using `streaming`. In papa parse the concept of `streaming` is to process the data as parser is reading them.

Basically, you will check for certain key in the `row` object returned in the `step` function. Check out the following code:

```
var allKeyPresent = false; // Flag

Papa.parse(file, {
    header : true,
    skipEmptyLines : true,
    step: function(row, parser){
        if (!allKeyPresent) { //Only chek if flag is not set, i.e, for the first time
            parser.pause(); // pause the parser
            var first_row_data = row.data[0];
            // Now check object keys, if it match
            if (('Extension' in first_row_data) && ('name' in first_row_data) && ('email' in first_row_data)) {
                //every required key is present
                allKeyPresent = true;

                // Do your data processing here

                parser.resume();
            } else{
                //some key is missing, abort parsing
                parser.abort();
            }

        } else{ // we already match the header, all required key is present

            // Do the Data processing here

        }

    }
});
```

To know more about streaming in papa parse check out [this](http://papaparse.com/faq#streaming). Also, see more about the `step` function in the config explanation section of the [documentation](http://papaparse.com/docs#config).

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any other related query.

Answer (score 2):

```
async importData(path:string){
        const planilha:any[] = [] 
        const unparsed = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8')             
        Papa.parse(unparsed,{   
            header:true,                
            skipEmptyLines:true,
            step:function(row,parser){
            if(row.meta.fields?.length!==4){
                    parser.abort()
                    fs.unlinkSync(path)
                    throw new BadRequestException('a planilha de importação deve ter 4 campos: name, phone,email e cpf nesta ordem e nestes formatos')
                }
                if(row.meta.fields[0]!=='name'){
                    parser.abort()
                    fs.unlinkSync(path)
                    throw new BadRequestException('o primeiro campo da planilha deve ser "name" ')
                }
                if(row.meta.fields[1]!=='phone'){
                    parser.abort()
                    fs.unlinkSync(path)
                    throw new BadRequestException('o segundo campo da planilha deve ser "phone" ')
                }
                if(row.meta.fields[2]!=='email'){
                    fs.unlinkSync(path)
                    throw new BadRequestException('o terceiro campo da planilha deve ser "email" ')
                }
                if(row.meta.fields[3]!=='cpf'){
                    parser.abort()
                    fs.unlinkSync(path)
                    throw new BadRequestException('o quarto campo da planilha deve ser "cpf" ')
                } 
                  
                    planilha.push(row.data)
                    parser.resume()             
                   
            }                               
        })
    fs.unlinkSync(path)
```

}